# AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sklearn-pandas

I was trying to import sklearn on my Jupyter Notebook but it gave me an error `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '__version__'`.
The whole description for the error is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     78     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     79     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 80     from .base import clone
     81     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     82 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>
     19 from . import __version__
     20 from ._config import get_config
---> 21 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     22 from .utils.validation import check_X_y
     23 from .utils.validation import check_array

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     24 from . import _joblib
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
      8 
      9 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <module>
     23 from contextlib import suppress
     24 
---> 25 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan, parse_version
     26 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     27 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning, PositiveSpectrumWarning

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py in <module>
     30 
     31 np_version = parse_version(np.__version__)
---> 32 sp_version = parse_version(scipy.__version__)
     33 
     34 

AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I tried to `pip uninstall scipy` and reinstall it, it wasn't working, and still cant fixed the problem. Does anyone here know how to fix it or encounter it before?

Comment: Sounds like you gave a file a name that clashes with something important. Don't name files the same as a standard module or a module you have installed.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica where did I name the files the same as the standard module? I am kinda confused with the error msg lol

Comment: Have you created a file called `scipy.py` in the directory where you are running Python?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The scipy.py is located ````/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/```` inside the site-packages folder

Comment: There should not be a `scipy.py` at all. Where did that come from?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think it came from either ````pip install or conda install````

Comment: Struggling here as well. Did you find anything?